How do I have a curved Gradient over multiple objects in in Illustrator?
I have multiple objects that I want a gradient applied to. The effect I am trying to create looks like this: 
I have created this effect by having a gradient on a curved stroke and having a box on top with holes. This does a great job of visualizing my idea, but I'm unable to export this as a transparent image. I have exported it as a high quality .png and removed the white background in photoshop as a quick fix, but I will need to export this as an .svg in the future. Any help is greatly appreciated!


Create a compound shape with your segments, place them on top of the stroke, then select the stroke and the segments and create a clipping mask.
